# Replace a trailing minus with leading minus

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace values which have a trailing minus sign and replace them with a leading minus sign. I've got this regex which doesn't quite work in SED though I don't understand why.

```
echo '8.8-' | sed 's/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)-/-\\1/'
```

SED returns 8.8-

I tried the expression in Notepad++ RegEx Help plugin which matches the 8.8- and identifies the sub-match \1 as 8.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\d` is a Perlism.  Sed refers to the older, pre-Perl, POSIX standard.  What you probably want is

```
echo '8.8-' | sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?)-/-\1/'
```

The `[[:digit:]]` is the POSIX way to write Perl's `\d`.

Of course, you can just write `[0-9]`, instead, as others have noted.

Incidentally, you need the `-r` to make your parentheses work as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`\d` does not match a digit character class in sed, `[0-9]` will though.

BTW please include what it is you're REALLY trying to do - are you working with numbers?  Ints and decimal?  I can deduce as much from your RegEx but shouldn't need to if the question is asked properly.

***EDIT***

If you're using GNU linux, better to use character classes than traditional ranges as they're more portable:

```
echo '8.8-' | sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?)-/-\1/'
```

http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '8- 8.1- 81.2- 8.28- 82.28-' | sed -r 's/([0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?)-/-\1/g'
```

Results in

```
-8 -8.1 -81.2 -8.28 -82.28
```

Sed simply doesn't understand \d or \d:

```
 echo "456" | sed -r 's/\d/+/g'
 456
```