# SED - Replace trailing minus sign

Tags: bash, sed

Good Evening,

I'm trying to replace a trailing minus sign with a leading minus sign. The link below was very helpful, but I'm having a hard time dealing with both a comma and period. For example:

Input Data:

```
|76534|     253,453.86-|       6/4/2012|  56487-56987|
|32567|      36,000.00|        7/8/2012|  45684-4541|
|58531|         400.56-|      10/5/2012|  15232-1254|
|12584|           5.56-|     12/12/2013|  125565-451|
```

Desired Results (all other columns remain the same):

```
-253,453.86
  36,000.00
    -400.56
      -5.56
```

Using `sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+(\,[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?))-/-\1/'` I've been able to treat numbers with a comma, but I would like to treat all types in one command if possible.

Helpful Link:
[Replace a trailing minus with leading minus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305531/replace-a-trailing-minus-with-leading-minus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work with your multi-column data:

```
sed -r '{s#([0-9][0-9,.]*)-\|#-\1\|#g}'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you all for your help.  I apologize again for any confusion.

Comment: As jaypal said, `awk` is almost always better for data that's explicitly divided into fields.

Comment: @ooga, except when you need regex substitution, which almost always looks awful in `awk` one-liners.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[:digit:],.]` to create a character class with numbers, commas and periods. The rest you already know how to do.

```
sed -r 's/([[:digit:].,])-/-\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$ sed '/-$/{s/-$//;s/[0-9]/-&/;b};s/^/ /' file
-253,453.86
  36,000.00
    -400.56
      -5.56
```

Updated Answer:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/-$/){sub(/-$/,"",$i);sub(/[0-9]/,"-&",$i)}}1' file
|76534|     -253,453.86|       6/4/2012|  56487-56987|
|32567|      36,000.00|        7/8/2012|  45684-4541|
|58531|         -400.56|      10/5/2012|  15232-1254|
|12584|           -5.56|     12/12/2013|  125565-451|
```

Comment: You should also add a space before a number without a `-` after it to maintain right-justification.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I didn't receive the results I was looking for.  Based on the expression above my negative signs are still trailing. I am making changes to a pipe delimited txt with numerous columns if that helps.

Comment: @ooga Good point, thanks and fixed. Not sure if it will help OP as he chose to post sample that does not represent his true data set.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if justification matters. Nice fix, though, using the `b` command like that. I was having trouble (embarrassingly) trying to use `n`, but I don't know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Posted. I apologize for any confusion. The true data set is roughly 100 columns by 50,000+ rows. I added the first couple columns to give a general idea.

Comment: @user3582260 I would recommend using `awk`. Check updated answer. It will iterate through all columns, and replace the trailing `-` where ever it finds and places it in front. I chose to iterate since you didn't mention the trailing data is fixed on a particular column.

Comment: My `sed` version works, too, with a global replace and an explicit match to end with `|`. I doubt it's as robust as your `awk` version, though. +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} sub(/-$/,"",$3){sub(/[^ ]/,"-&",$3)}1' file
|76534|     -253,453.86|       6/4/2012|  56487-56987|
|32567|      36,000.00|        7/8/2012|  45684-4541|
|58531|         -400.56|      10/5/2012|  15232-1254|
|12584|           -5.56|     12/12/2013|  125565-451|
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one through GNU `sed`,

```
$ sed -r 's/^(\|[0-9]+\|)( *?)([^|]*?)(-)(.*)$/\1\2\4\3\5/g' file
|76534|     -253,453.86|       6/4/2012|  56487-56987|
|32567|      36,000.00|        7/8/2012|  45684-4541|
|58531|         -400.56|      10/5/2012|  15232-1254|
|12584|           -5.56|     12/12/2013|  125565-451|
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\-|/-\1|/' input
```